# How to set UNION inside UNION ALL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union, union-all

I'm trying to execute this code :

```
SELECT ItName, ItCode, Qty, Qt2, Qt3
FROM
(
SELECT A.ItName, A.ItCode, COUNT(B.Qty) AS 'Quantity 1', COUNT(B.Qty2) AS 'Quantity 2', 
COUNT(B.Qty3) AS 'Quantity 3' 
FROM tblitem A
INNER JOIN tblstocksummary B ON A.ItCode = B.ItCode
WHERE A.Itcode='IL001-000151'
GROUP BY A.ItCode
HAVING COUNT(B.Qty) !='0'AND COUNT(B.Qty2) !='0' AND COUNT(B.Qty3) !='0'

UNION

SELECT A2.ItName, A2.ItCode, COUNT(B2.Qty), COUNT(B2.Qty2), COUNT(B2.Qty3) FROM tblitem A2
INNER JOIN tblstocksummary B2 ON A2.ItCode = B2.ItCode
WHERE A2.Itcode='IL001-000373' 
GROUP BY A2.ItCode
HAVING COUNT(B2.Qty) !='0'AND COUNT(B2.Qty2) !='0' AND COUNT(B2.Qty3) !='0'
) t
UNION ALL

SELECT A3.ItName, A3.ItCode, COUNT(B3.Qty), COUNT(B3.Qty2), COUNT(B3.Qty3) FROM tblitem A3
INNER JOIN tblstocksummary B3 ON A2.ItCode = B3.ItCode
WHERE A3.Itcode='IL001-000166' 
GROUP BY A3.ItCode
HAVING COUNT(B3.Qty) !='0'AND COUNT(B3.Qty2) !='0' AND COUNT(B3.Qty3) !='0';
```

But I got error :

> SQL Error(1054): Unknown column 'Qty' in field list

So, I guess that either I am using wrong syntax or I am trying to do something that can not be done. Maybe most likely experienced people will see right away what is wrong.

Can someone help me, please ? Thanks

Comment: Change the aliases 'Quantity 1',  'Quantity 2' and 'Quantity 3' to Qty, Qt2 and Qt3.

Comment: I have a feeling that this query can be much.. much shorter.

Comment: @FaNo_FN I thought so too, but I don't know how. Maybe you can give me some advice ?

Comment: I can if you have table and sample data for me to work on. Also a desired result would be good. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68112081/edit) to include them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For three different `A.ItCode` you don't need three different select query to combine with union all, rather you can use `in` clause to get three different products with single select query.

```
SELECT A.ItCode, A.ItName, COUNT(B.Qty) 'Quantity', COUNT(B.Qty2) 'Quantity2', COUNT(B.Qty3) 'Quantity3'
FROM tblitem A
INNER JOIN tblstocksummary B ON A.ItCode = B.ItCode AND A.ItCode in ('IL001-000151','IL001-000373', 'IL001-000166')
GROUP BY A.ItCode 
HAVING 'Quantity' !='0' AND 'Quantity2' !='0' AND 'Quantity3' !='0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `Quantity1` `Quantity2` as columns not Qty

Maybe try this

```
SELECT ItName, ItCode, Qty, Qt2, Qt3
FROM
(
SELECT A.ItName, A.ItCode, COUNT(B.Qty) AS 'Qty', COUNT(B.Qty2) AS 'Qty2', 
COUNT(B.Qty3) AS 'Qty3' 
FROM tblitem A
INNER JOIN tblstocksummary B ON A.ItCode = B.ItCode
WHERE A.Itcode='IL001-000151'
GROUP BY A.ItCode
HAVING COUNT(B.Qty) !='0'AND COUNT(B.Qty2) !='0' AND COUNT(B.Qty3) !='0'

UNION

SELECT A2.ItName, A2.ItCode, COUNT(B2.Qty), COUNT(B2.Qty2), COUNT(B2.Qty3) FROM tblitem A2
INNER JOIN tblstocksummary B2 ON A2.ItCode = B2.ItCode
WHERE A2.Itcode='IL001-000373' 
GROUP BY A2.ItCode
HAVING COUNT(B2.Qty) !='0'AND COUNT(B2.Qty2) !='0' AND COUNT(B2.Qty3) !='0'
) t
UNION ALL

SELECT A3.ItName, A3.ItCode, COUNT(B3.Qty), COUNT(B3.Qty2), COUNT(B3.Qty3) FROM tblitem A3
INNER JOIN tblstocksummary B3 ON A2.ItCode = B3.ItCode
WHERE A3.Itcode='IL001-000166' 
GROUP BY A3.ItCode
HAVING COUNT(B3.Qty) !='0'AND COUNT(B3.Qty2) !='0' AND COUNT(B3.Qty3) !='0';
```

Comment: Still have the same error with this code, but this time the error is unknown 'Qty2' in field list. But I appreciate your help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have more problems than just wrong aliasses:

This is the correct code(code without errors):

```
    SELECT ItName, ItCode, `Quantity 1`, `Quantity 2`, `Quantity 3`
FROM
(
SELECT A.ItName, A.ItCode, COUNT(B.Qty) AS 'Quantity 1', COUNT(B.Qty2) AS 'Quantity 2', 
COUNT(B.Qty3) AS 'Quantity 3' 
FROM tblitem A
INNER JOIN tblstocksummary B ON A.ItCode = B.ItCode
WHERE A.Itcode='IL001-000151'
GROUP BY  A.ItName, A.ItCode
HAVING COUNT(B.Qty) !='0'AND COUNT(B.Qty2) !='0' AND COUNT(B.Qty3) !='0'

UNION

SELECT A2.ItName, A2.ItCode, COUNT(B2.Qty), COUNT(B2.Qty2), COUNT(B2.Qty3) 
FROM tblitem A2
INNER JOIN tblstocksummary B2 ON A2.ItCode = B2.ItCode
WHERE A2.Itcode='IL001-000373' 
GROUP BY A2.ItName, A2.ItCode
HAVING COUNT(B2.Qty) !='0'AND COUNT(B2.Qty2) !='0' AND COUNT(B2.Qty3) !='0'
) t
UNION ALL

SELECT A3.ItName, A3.ItCode, COUNT(B3.Qty), COUNT(B3.Qty2), COUNT(B3.Qty3) FROM tblitem A3
INNER JOIN tblstocksummary B3 ON A3.ItCode = B3.ItCode
WHERE A3.Itcode='IL001-000166' 
GROUP BY A3.ItName, A3.ItCode
HAVING COUNT(B3.Qty) !='0'AND COUNT(B3.Qty2) !='0' AND COUNT(B3.Qty3) !='0';
```

- I have replaced `Qty, Qty2 and Qty3` with `'Quantity 1', 'Quantity 2', 'Quantity 3'`
- Also replaced `ON A2.ItCode = B3.ItCode` with `ON A3.ItCode = B3.ItCode` where you can see that your table alias is
  wrong for this query.
- I have added a coulmn `ItName` in every group
  by.

Here is my demo: [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f21a118712bddbf5b516834ab8607b84)

Comment: Shouldn't `'Quantity 1', 'Quantity 2', 'Quantity 3'` on the outer query be wrapped within backticks instead of apostrophes?

Comment: doesn't have the same error, but this time in column Quantity 1 ,2 and 3. It return 'Quantity 1', Quantity 2, and Quantity 3 for the 1st and 2nd row

Comment: That's because of the apostrophe. The referred alias should be wrapped in backticks instead. [Refer this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9d9d5068e2a0330ff5d1d53154c286bd)

Comment: I have corrected my answer and the code in the demo. Thanks @FaNo_FN for your correction. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this and it worked just like I want

```
SELECT A.ItCode 'Item Code', A.ItName 'Item Name', COUNT(B.Qty) 'Quantity', COUNT(B.Qty2) 'Quantity2', COUNT(B.Qty3) 'Quantity3'
FROM tblitem A
INNER JOIN tblstocksummary B ON A.ItCode = B.ItCode AND A.ItCode = 'IL001-000151'
GROUP BY A.ItCode 
HAVING 'Quantity' !='0' AND 'Quantity2' !='0' AND 'Quantity3' !='0'

UNION ALL 

SELECT A.ItCode, A.ItName, COUNT(B.Qty) 'Quantity', COUNT(B.Qty2) 'Quantity2', COUNT(B.Qty3) 'Quantity3'
FROM tblitem A
INNER JOIN tblstocksummary B ON A.ItCode = B.ItCode AND A.ItCode = 'IL001-000373'
GROUP BY A.ItCode 
HAVING 'Quantity' !='0' AND 'Quantity2' !='0' AND 'Quantity3' !='0'

UNION ALL

SELECT A.ItCode, A.ItName, COUNT(B.Qty) 'Quantity', COUNT(B.Qty2) 'Quantity2', COUNT(B.Qty3) 'Quantity3'
FROM tblitem A
INNER JOIN tblstocksummary B ON A.ItCode = B.ItCode AND A.ItCode = 'IL001-000166'
GROUP BY A.ItCode 
HAVING 'Quantity' !='0' AND 'Quantity2' !='0' AND 'Quantity3' !='0'
```

But I think this code can be shorter. But I don't know how to short it. Any advice ?

Comment: You can use one select query for those three products. Please check my answer.